# Why the AWS lambda function, throws "Endpoint request timed out ". Message?

Tags: aws-lambda, request-timed-out

After closing and refreshing the session, it endpoint works fine. Is it because the next call is trying to access the already executing instance.

I want to know the reason for this error and also if there is a way to automatically refresh the endpoint after each execution

Comment: Closing and refreshing what session exactly? Please provide enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also getting this after we adding a VPC Peering Connection.  Not sure how to get past it yet.  Any luck for you?

Answer (score -4):

The "Endpoint request timed out" error message in the context of AWS Lambda usually indicates that the Lambda function was trying to communicate with an external resource, such as an API, database, or another AWS service, and the connection or request to that external resource took longer than the configured timeout duration.

Here are a few common reasons why you might encounter this error:

External Resource Slowness: If your Lambda function is making a network request to an external API, database, or service, and that resource is slow to respond, the Lambda function might time out waiting for the response.

Long-Running Operations: If the Lambda function is performing a task that takes longer to complete than the timeout set for the function, it will result in a timeout error.

Network Latency: Network latency between the Lambda execution environment and the external resource can contribute to timeouts if the response takes too long to arrive.

Insufficient Resources: If your Lambda function is running with limited resources (memory or execution time), it might not have the capacity to handle certain operations efficiently, leading to timeouts.

Concurrency Limits: If you're hitting the concurrency limits for your Lambda function or the external resource you're trying to access, it can lead to timeouts due to resource contention.

Configuration Errors: Incorrect configuration settings, such as specifying incorrect endpoints or URLs, can cause your Lambda function to timeout when trying to reach external resources.

Comment: Don't copy/paste from ChatGPT or similar engines.